# Next and previous links and ID displayed in the URL for sharing

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, button

I have a database with a few images already set, I would like to have the url display an ID from each query as the user hits next. The user should be able to share the URL and paste it into their browser, the url should pull that unique ID from the query. The issue i am having is every time i paste a url, I get a random image and not the image that is in the ID. I'm at a loss here and im not sure what to do :( here's the code I have so far.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    include("PHP/db.php");

    echo $where = $_GET["id"];
    echo $query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE ID =" . $where;

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $ID = $row['ID'];
    $title = $row['name'];

    $image =  "<img height=500 width=600 src=http://www.goupics.com/img/" . $row['name'] . " >";
}

if($_GET['next4']) {
    echo 'HELLO THIS IS THE NEXT IF METHOD';

    include("PHP/db.php");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $ID = $row['ID'];
    $title = $row['name'];

    $image =  "<img height=500 width=600 src=http://www.goupics.com/img/" . $row['name'] . " >";
} 

?>
<body>
</div>
    <div id="title"> <?php echo $title ?> </div>

    <div id="mainpic">
    <?php echo $image ?>
    </div>

    <div id="prevnext">
        <div id="next">
        <a href="?id=<?php echo $ID ?>" name="name4" >Next</a>
        </div>

        <div id="prev">
            <a href="?id=<?php echo $ID ?>">Previous</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: $dbc is the connection to my mysql database which is pulled from the included file

include("PHP/db.php");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
include("PHP/db.php");

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
$rand_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
$rand_id = $rand_row ['ID'];

if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $_GET['id'] = $rand_id;
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo $where = $_GET["id"];
    echo $query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE ID =" . $where;

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $ID = $row['ID'];
    $title = $row['name'];
    $image = "<img height=500 width=600 src=http://www.goupics.com/img/" . $row['name'] . " >";
}
?>

<body>
</div>
    <div id="title"> <?php echo $title ?> </div>

    <div id="mainpic">
    <?php echo $image ?>
    </div>

    <div id="prevnext">
        <div id="next">
            <a href="?id=<?php echo $rand_id; ?>" name="name4" >Next</a>
        </div>

        <div id="prev">
            <a href="?id=rand">Previous</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I changed:

-link to next is now id=rand
-changed your code to give me a "rand ID" and its already defined on the href of the page you load

Answer (score 1):

It will go inside condition `(next == true)`.

Make sure that your variables are initialized before use.

Comment: That if statement if ONLY suppose to go off if the user clicks next but it goes off anyway even if i put a custom URL with an ID.